# Avoid code repeat

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code that searchs words in Word file using a VBA Excel macro and paste them to Excel sheet cells, but my code for now repeat the same find function multiple times:

```
Sub test()
Dim Word As Object
Dim WordDoc As Object
Dim r, f As Boolean, fO As Long
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Filename:=Application.ThisWorkbook.path & "\test.docx")
'''Name'''
Set r = WordDoc.Range
Do
With r.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "name*author"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    If .Execute Then
                If f Then
                    If r.Start = fO Then
                Exit Do
                    End If
                Else
                    fO = r.Start
                    f = True
                End If
                WordDoc.Range(r.Start + 4, r.End - 6).Copy
                Range("C4").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Set r = WordDoc.Range(r.End, r.End)
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        End With
    Loop
'''Exercise'''
Set r = WordDoc.Range
Do
With r.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "exercise*book"
    ...
                WordDoc.Range(r.Start + 8, r.End - 4).Copy
                Range("C6").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Set r = WordDoc.Range(r.End, r.End)
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        End With
    Loop
End Sub
```

How to avoid code repeat?

Can someone help me with these? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean copying and pasting the same function repeartedly?

Comment: Indent your code properly as well and then it will be more obvious the differences between the first loop and the second loop which mean, if you want to refactor that section, you will need to do some thinking about all potential use cases to write the right helper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the repeated code to a function/sub like this:

```
Set r = WordDoc.Range
Do While UnifiedSearch (r, "name*author")
    If f Then
        If r.Start = fO Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Else
        fO = r.Start
        f = True
    End If
    WordDoc.Range(r.Start + 4, r.End - 6).Copy
    Range("C4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Set r = WordDoc.Range(r.End, r.End)
Loop
'''Exercise'''
Set r = WordDoc.Range
Do While UnifiedSearch (r, "exercise*book")
    WordDoc.Range(r.Start + 8, r.End - 4).Copy
    Range("C6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Set r = WordDoc.Range(r.End, r.End)
Loop
End Sub

Private Function UnifiedSearch(r as Range, s As String) As Boolean

     With r.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = s
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        UnifiedSearch = .Execute
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: When I run the code I get a "compile error: Object required" on this line: `Set r = WordDoc.Range`. What I need to change?

Comment: This line is just an indication to show you where to insert my snippet into your code.

Comment: I understood this, but still gives an error.
I tried to remove "Set" in this line, but then I get another error: `ByRef argument type mismatch`

Comment: Try to use a valid starting point for the search, e.g. `Set r = WordDoc.Range(0, 0)`. NB: You must `Set` the value of an object, e.g. a `Range`.

Comment: `Set r = WordDoc.Range(0, 0)` don't work, still gives the same error.

Comment: This can happen when you can not open the desired file so `WordDoc Is Nothing`. Please check. Anyhow, it is adviseable to check the success of all IO operations.

Comment: I figured it out. I changed: `Dim r As Boolean` and `Private Function UnifiedSearch(r as Range, s As String) As Boolean` to `Dim r As Object` and `Private Function UnifiedSearch(r As Object, s As String) As Boolean`, and now it works!